# How to I find the last three digits of a number that is the result of 2^(a^b)

Tags: python, math, shortcut

In Python, I am trying to figure out how to find the last three digits of a number that is the result of 2^(a^b) with a and b as the imput values. It handles input values up to 6, 6 without slowing down, but once it gets to 7, 7 it becomes very slow, and 8, 8 just doesnt work. I was wondering if there was some kind of mathematical shortcut or something to get the last three digits faster. Also, I am kind of new to stack overflow, so I don't know if I am asking this in the right place. Also, I am using replit if that changes anything. (This is for school and I would really appreciate help)

```
def last_three(a, b):
  num = 2 ** (a ** b)
  string = str(num)
  length = len(string)
  print (length)
  new_string = ''
  new_string += string[length - 3]
  new_string += string[length - 2]
  new_string += string[length - 1]
  return int(new_string)
```

Comment: This isn't really a _programming_ question; you're expected to know a better way of doing this than just calculating the whole number and throwing away the rest.  Of course, you might start by doing this without constructing the full-length string first...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is fundamentally a math question, not a programming question. Please try https://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Disagree.  All the necessary math is contained in the line `num = 2 ** (a ** b)`, and that's already in there.  Finding the last three digits looks like a programming problem to me.  And the OP clearly states his confusion that 6, 6 works and 8, 8 does not.  Again, a programming not a math issue.  That he has chosen a poor algorithm for the problem at hand is something that can be explained in programming terms.

Comment: Hint: x % 1000 is a number equal to the last three decimal digits of x, assuming x is a positive integer.  In python, % is the modulo operator.

Comment: Hey Paul! It worked! I can't believe I missed such an easy solution! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey Davis and Karl. Thanks for the feedback. As I said, I am new to stack overflow, so I didn't know if this was the right place to ask this question. I will make sure not to ask questions like these on stack overflow again.

Comment: I suspect it's a math problem, or else it's not an interesting problem at all. Try computing 2^(10000000000 ^ 10000000000) mod 1000 for example. The trick involves knowing something about how the Euler totient function works (or, alternatively, Carmichael's lambda function)

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I did that yesterday, although figured out that 2^3 and 2^103 are congruent modulo 1000 just with a little program. So I can compute the result with `pow(2, (pow(10**10, 10**10, 100) - 3) % 100 + 3, 1000)`. I have trouble generalizing that, though. I can't do `pow(2, (pow(a, b, 100) - 3) % 100 + 3, 1000)` because that's wrong if `a**b` is less than 3. I guess I could do some `if else` looking at `a` and `b`, but that feels inelegant. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @KellyBundy: I've done this problem before somewhere, I think on codewars. If I remember my reasoning, we are compute 2^x mod N, and this is equivalent to 2^y mod N where y=x mod phi(N). Now we note that x=a^b mod phi(N), and this is equivalent to a^c mod phi(N) where c=b mod phi(phi(N)). By continuing with this reasoning you can find the solution to very long modular "tower of powers" that would otherwise be impossible to compute. But it was a little more complicated because a^phi(N) = 1 mod N only if gcd(a, N) == 1. This is all from memory so I'm sure I have errors here.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yes, such "towers" were my next interest and then I would've tried something like phi (which I vaguely remember). I think your statement about 2^y mod N being equivalent might be true if the gcd is 1, but with 2 and 1000, that's not the case, causing my issue. In particular, phi(1000) is 400, but 2^0 and 2^400 aren't congruent modulo 1000 (they're congruent to 1 and 376, respectively).

Comment: @KellyBundy: for when gcd(a,n) > 1 there is more general identity that is useful. [Here it is stated for carmichael's lambda function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Exponential_cycle_length) but there is also a version for Euler's phi function, though I can't find it on Wikipedia. [Here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a08b22b32b8b96f4700001c) is the codewars problem.

Comment: Or one more option: `376 * pow(2, pow(a, b, 100), 125) % 1000` (again valid only for the case `a**b >= 3`).

Comment: @KellyBundy: Sorry, I totally missed your earlier comment - too much multitasking. That's embarrassing. I'll delete my duplicate comments. For `a**b < 3`, I'd just do a boring case-by-case check: if `a < 2` or `b = 0` or (`b = 1` and `a = 2`), we're in the `a**b < 3` case; otherwise not). So the inelegant way. I don't see anything obviously better.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yeah, such a case-by-case check is the inelegant way I was hoping to avoid :-). It also won't help with further generalized versions of the problem, like the power tower that the president pointed out. Maybe I'll find something better in the material they mentioned or while solving that codewars problem.

Comment: The test `b * (a.bit_length() - 1) < 2` is equivalent to `a**b < 4`, for natural numbers `a` and `b`. Not hugely elegant, but it at least gives a one-line expression: `2**(a**b) if b * (a.bit_length() - 1) < 2 else 376 * pow(2, pow(a, b, 100), 125) % 1000`.

Comment: Hmm. Actually, just `b * (a - 1) < 2` is better: it's directly equivalent to `a**b < 3`. So just `2**(a**b) if b * (a - 1) < 2 else 376 * pow(2, pow(a, b, 100), 125) % 1000` should work.

Comment: Someone conveniently [wrote an entire paper](https://core.ac.uk/reader/34619570) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the equation is not the slow part, it was the fact that I was converting it to a string, finding the length, and indexing the last 3 digits.

One of the comments told me to do `2**(a**b) % 1000` to get the solution, and it worked.

Thank you all for the feedback.

Comment: `pow(2, (a**b), 1000)` will work faster.

Comment: Careful. In python, as in most programming languages, `a^b` does **not** mean "a to the power of b". It means "a bitwise-xor b", which is completely unrelated to what you want. In python, use `a**b` or `pow(a, b)` to get "a to the power of b".

Comment: I'd like to insist on @bb1's comment. `pow(2, (a**b), 1000)` is not just a little faster than `2 ** (a**b) % 1000`. It's much more efficient. Especially if `a` and `b` are large, `2 ** (a ** b)` can be a **huge** number, whereas the result of `2 ** (a**b) % 1000` is always a small number (less than 1000). There are tricks to compute this small number using only small numbers, which is much more efficient than calculating the huge number `2 ** (a ** b)`. Python's builtin function `pow` takes advantage of these tricks.

Comment: @Stef You say "small number (less than 1000)" and then "using only small numbers". Do you mean that it completely only uses numbers less than 1000? I'd imagine it to go up to 999^2 for a moment before it right away modulos it back down to less than 1000. But I guess it could truly stay under 1000 the whole time, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @KellyBundy I haven't studied these kinds of arithmetics in a years so, no, I can't guarantee that all numbers manipulated are less than 1000. But they're certainly small compared to `2**(a**b)`. Going up to `999**2` sounds very reasonable in this case; although if we replace 1000 by `2**32`, where 32 is the word-size on a computer, then I guess it would be desirable to only manipulate numbers less than `2**32` when computing `2**(a**b) % 2**32`.